# SILK module generator add single table module

Tags: module, magento-1, development

I'm trying to figure out what the function of "Add Single Table Model" is in the [SILK Magento Module Generator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator). I see it ads a table in admin, but is this table for anything specifically or can I display any data I want? Where is this data stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "table" is a grid, then yes, you can display any data you want. There is a `_prepareCollection` and a `_prepareLayout` method in the block, the collection method is to prepare the collection (haha) join all the tables together and select the columns you want. The layout method is about adding the columns from the select statement into the grid, defined what type they have to filter them, etc.